# SwiftUI private route based on Authentication Status

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I need to implement a mechanism just like react private and public route on swiftUI. Basically I have tens of views and some of these views requires authentication based on user logged in status. So far I have tried to hold current screen in an Environment Object as show in following class

```
    enum Routes {
    case screenA,
         screenB,
         screenC,
         screenD,
         screenE,
         screenF,
         screenG,
         loginScreen
    
    var isAuthRequired: Bool {
            if case . screenA = self {
                return true
            } else if case . screenD = self {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
}

class AuthenticatedRoute: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentRoute: Routes
    
    init(){
        self.currentRoute = . screenA
    }
}
```

And on my main screen I check every time the current screen change whether user loggedin and current page require authentication.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var authenticatedRoute = AuthenticatedRoute()
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth
    
    var body: some View {
        mainView()
            .environmentObject(authenticatedRoute)
    }
    
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func mainView() -> some View {
        if (self.authenticatedRoute.currentRoute.isAuthRequired && !userAuth.isLoggedIn) {
            LoginView()
        }
        else {
            DefaultTabView()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an example of how I keep changing this environment variable. I change the environment object onAppear event method of view.

```
struct ScreenA: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authenticatedRoute: AuthenticatedRoute
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            someContent()
        }.onAppear {
            authenticatedRoute.currentRoute = .screenA
        }
    }
}
```

While this approach works for most cases for some reason it behave strange when a screen is in tab navigation. Also I do not feel comfortable with this solution, that I need to change screen name manually on every single page, and checking authentication status in main view. I think it would be better somehow if I can write a kind of interceptor before every page change and check if desired destination requires authentication and if user is authenticated but I could not find a way manage this. I'm relatively new to iOS development and had experience with react native but this should not be so hard to implement in my opinion since this is a requirement for most applications.

So basically I need to implement a private and public router in swiftUI or intercept every page change so I should not modify environment variable on each pages manually and should not check conditions in MainView inside a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can propose another approach, that does not require the class `AuthenticatedRoute`, I hope it's what you are looking for. The process is:

1. In the class `UserAuth`, create a static `shared` instance, that can be called anywhere in your code and ensures you are always using the same instance.
2. Create a modifier extending `View`, that reads the status in `UserAuth.shared` and shows the necessary view according to whether the authentication is required (`LoginView()` if the user is not authenticated).
3. Use the modifier at the outermost container (`VStack`, `NavigationView`, whatever) of any view that requires the user to be authenticated.

The example below shows how this can work, if you want to run it:

**1. Static `UserAuth` instance**

```
class UserAuth: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = UserAuth()     // This is to assure that you refer to the same instance all over the code
    
    @Published private(set) var isLoggedIn = false    // Use the variable you already have
    
    func logInOrOff() {     // Implement each func as needed
        isLoggedIn.toggle()
    }
}
```

**2. Create the `View` modifier**

```
extension View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func requiresAuthentication() -> some View {
        if UserAuth.shared.isLoggedIn {  // "shared" is the same instance used by the views
            self
        } else {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Apply the modifier at the bottom of the view that requires authentication**

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @StateObject private var userAuth = UserAuth.shared    //  Or @EnvironmentObject, as you wish
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(userAuth.isLoggedIn ? "Now we're good" : "You must log in")
                .padding()
            
            Button {
                userAuth.logInOrOff()
            } label: {
                Text("Logoff")
            }
        }
        .requiresAuthentication()    // This is what makes your view safe
    }
}

struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Authentication is required")
                .padding()
            
            Button {
                UserAuth.shared.logInOrOff()
            } label: {
                Text("Log in")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm thank you, but it is kinda sad that we can't intercept navigation or writing a router is hard in swiftUI. I really liked to keep track of current screen without much hassle